# The cute little blue box on flag dialogs

Tags: script

#### About

Based on [Use the same location for Submit button in the comment flag dialog as in the post flag dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316903/use-the-same-location-for-submit-button-in-the-comment-flag-dialog-as-in-the-pos) which asked for the buttons to go on the right side, and [Question Close Updates: Phase 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396754/question-close-updates-phase-1) which moved all the buttons to the left side side instead, and removed the little box surrounding the number of remaining flags, I wanted to "fix it" with this script. It will:

- Bring back the little blue box.
- Put the buttons back on the right side.
- Add elipsis to the options that will open op a new dialog.
- Make the apperance of radios, text, and size consistent.
- Applies to post flag, comment flag, and close vote dialogs both in and outside of reviews.
- Consistency also applies to the "Reject" dialog of suggested edits both in the queue and in-post tasks.

#### Screenshot

##### Before

[image: Before]

##### After

[image: After]

The script is compatible with the "*-pls Request Generator" listed in the [SOCVR Userscripts](https://socvr.org/tools/userscripts#our-scripts) section:

[image: After]

#### Sites

The script only works for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), since adding the ellipsis is done depending on the option text, which is site specific.

#### Platform

Should work with any user script manager & any browser running JavaScript.
Tested using Opera with [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

#### Download

[GitHub](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/tree/main/StackFlagDialog) | [Install](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackFlagDialog/StackFlagDialog.user.js)

#### Contact

For bugs, please post here. Comments are fine too.